# How to extract List of objects from ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey-2.0

This is my get API returning list of employees.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/get")
public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
    return employeeFacade.getAllEmployee();
}
```

I want to extract the `Employee` object from `ResponseEntity<String>`.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
//headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

Employee employee = new Employee();

HttpEntity<Employee> entity = new HttpEntity<Employee>(employee, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

System.out.println("result:" + result);
```

**How to make this work ?**

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: Can we look at your response json?

Comment: Why do you use `String.class`is what you want is an Employee, and not a String?

Comment: if i am using employee.class it gives an error because i want to extract list of employee not a single employee .sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: You can pass 'new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Employee>>() {}'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the API call is returning `List` of `Employee` objects as JSON then you can directly parse that JSON into `List<Employee>` object by using `ParameterizedTypeReference`

```
ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity,  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Employee>>() {});
```

`getBody()` will return the response body

```
List<Employee> emps = result.getBody();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;`

`Employee employee = new ObjectMapper().readValue(result.getBody(),
Employee.class);`

Also if you use `getForObject()` instead of `exchange()`, you can also get the Employee object directly. Yeah, you don't have to pass `String.class` argument but `Employee.class`

**EDIT (if i want to extract list. how to do that??)**

So there are two way of doing the same.

[1] Use wrapper class

```
public class EmployeeList {
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public EmployeeList() {
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // standard constructor and getter/setter
}
```

```
ResponseEntity<EmployeeList> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, EmployeeList.class);
```

[2] Use ParameterizedTypeReference

```
ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity,  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Employee>>() {});
List<Employee> emps = result.getBody();
```

Comment: Creating a new ObjectMapper on each response is expensive and bad practice.

Comment: That's why I gave another solution

Comment: What is the best practice then? BTW

Comment: Since this is just a piece of code, not whole program here, you can declare ObjectMapper as static. This is thread safe.
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Comment: if i want to extract list<Employee>. how to do that??

Comment: Best practice in a spring boot app is to `@Autowire` in the default objectmapper that spring already has.